# Is there an efficient way to separate lines into different file, awk in this case?

Tags: string, awk, pattern-matching

I am trying to separate a file into two different files based on whether the line contains certain string. If a line contain "ITS", this line and the line right after it will be write to file ITS.txt; if a line contains "V34" then this line and the line right after it will be write to file "V34.txt".
My awk code is

```
awk '/ITS/{print>"ITX.txt";getline;print>"ITX.txt";}; /V34/{print>"V34.txt";getline;print>"V34.txt";}' seqs.fna
```

It works well. But I am wondering whether there is an efficient way to do so?

seqs.fna (9-10G)

```
   >16S.V34.S7.5_1
    ACGGGAGGCAGCAGTAGGGAATCTTCC
    >PCR.ITS.S8.14_2 
    CATTTAGAGGAAGTAAAAGTCGTAACA
    >PCR.ITS.S7.11_3
    CATTTAGAGGAAGTACAAGTCGTAACAAGGTTTCCGTAGGTGAACCTGCGGAAGGATCATTTTTGAAGGCTACAC
    >16S.V34.S8.6_4 
    ACGGGCGGCAGCAGTAGGGAAT
    >16S.V34.S8.13_5 
    ACGGGCGGCAGCAGTAGGGAATCTTCCGCAATGGGCGAAAGCCTGACGGAGCAACGCCGCGTGAGTGATGAAGGTCTTCGGATCGTAAAACTCTGT
    >16S.V34.S7.14_6
    ACGGGGGGCAGCAGTAGGGAATCTTCCACAATGGGTGCAAACCTGATGGAGCAATGCCG
    >16S.V34.S8.4_7 
    ACGGGAGGCAGCAGTAGGGAATCTTCCACAAT
    >16S.V34.S8.14_8 
    CGTAGAGATGTGGAGGAACACCAGTGGCGAAG
    >16S.V34.S8.8_9 
    CTGGGATAACACTGACGCTCATGCACGAAAGCGTGGGGAGCAAACAGGATTAGATACCCTTGTAGTC
    >16S.V34.S7.3_10 
    GGTCTGTAATTGACGCTGAGGTTCGAAAGCGTGGGGAGCGAACAGGATTAGATACCCGGGTAGTC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getline` has a few very specific uses and this would not be one of them. See http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline. If you rewrote your script without getline you'd solve the problem yourself but given the input file you posted, this is all you need:

```
awk -F'.' '/^>/{out=$2".txt"} {print > out}' seqs.fna
```

To learn how to use awk correctly, read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: Thank you for your quick elegant response. Works perfectly.

Comment: How about this one. It seems use less time than your method on a about 7G file.  `awk '/ITS/{getline X;print $0 RS x>"sl_out/2fungi.fna";}; /V34/{getline x;print $0 RS x>"sl_out/216s.fna";}' ./sl_out/seqs.fna`

Comment: `it seems to use less time` - I doubt it. If there is a time difference though, it'll be inconsequential/tiny but provide 3rd-iteration timing stats in your question if you'd like to discuss. Awk is not C. Like with any other tool/language you need to learn the paradigm, not just the syntax, to use it effectively. Again, read http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline to understand when/how to use getline (your code will produce unexpected output in some situations) and just look at the unnecessary duplication in your code. Now add a debugging `print` to print every line read - hard, right?

Comment: To print every line read to stdout for debugging with my idiomatic version: `awk -F'.' '{print} /^>/{out=$2".txt"} {print > out}'`, and now with your getline version: `awk '/ITS/{print; getline x; print x; print $0 RS x>"sl_out/2fungi.fna";}; /V34/{print; getline x; print x; print $0 RS x>"sl_out/216s.fna";}'`. You have to add the `print` in 1 place with the non-getline script and in 4 places with the getline script. That's just a trivial example of how use of getline messes up the natural control flow of an awk script and so makes it harder to enhance, debug or do anything else with later.

Comment: Here is some test results for running time. `$ /usr/bin/time -v awk '/ITS/{getline X;print $0 RS x>"fungi.fna";}; /V34/{getline x;print $0 RS x>"16s.fna";}' seqs.fna 
 User time (seconds): 146.72
 System time (seconds): 13.22
 Percent of CPU this job got: 99%
 Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 2:40.89
$ /usr/bin/time -v awk -F'.' '/^>/{out=$2".txt"} {print > out}' seqs.fna 
 User time (seconds): 303.66
 System time (seconds): 13.76
 Percent of CPU this job got: 99%
 Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 5:18.92` on a 7.5G file

Comment: Like I said, `...provide 3rd-iteration timing stats **in your question** if you'd like to discuss`. It's far too messy to try to read in a comment. Make sure the time stats you post are for the 3rd consecutive run of each command to remove any cacheing impact and also post the results of "diff" on the output files between the 2 versions to make sure they're both producing the same output.